# CL_INVALID_WORK_GROUP_SIZE opencl

Tags: c++, opencl

I'm getting **`CL_INVALID_WORK_GROUP_SIZE`**, but my local work size is 299 and my max supported **`WORK_GROUP_SIZE`** is 1024.

According to the documentation:

> CL_INVALID_WORK_GROUP_SIZE if local_work_size is specified and number
>   of work-items specified by global_work_size is not evenly divisable by
>   size of work-group given by local_work_size or does not match the
>   work-group size specified for kernel using the
>   **attribute**((reqd_work_group_size(X, Y, Z))) qualifier in program source.

in my case I have

```
size_t globalWorkSize[2] = { 299, 299 };
size_t localWorkSize[2] = { 299, 299 };
mErr = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(mCmdQueue, mKernel[0], 2, nullptr,
                globalWorkSize, localWorkSize, 0, nullptr, nullptr);
```

It seems to me I have 299^2 work groups of 1 work item each, I don't get where the problem is to be honest.

The question is why am I getting that error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CL\_INVALID\_WORK\_GROUP\_SIZE error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7996537/cl-invalid-work-group-size-error)

Comment: You local worksize  is actually 299*299 which is greater than 1024, you are trying to enqueue 1 workgroup of size 299*299. You should also check CL_KERNEL_WORK_GROUP_SIZE which could be less than the CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE.

Comment: @kanna has the right answer. Both those values apply to the total number of work-items in a group, not just one dimension. You'll need to make your group smaller.

Comment: @kanna - make that an answer (it is correct).

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to enqueue 1 workgroup of size 299*299 which is greater than 1024 i.e. `CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE`.

Also based on the kernel device might not be able to run `CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE` in a workgroup.
Correct approach is to make sure local work size is less than or equal to  `CL_KERNEL_WORK_GROUP_SIZE` which could be less than `CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE`.